# Login Issues in JSP

Tags: java, jsp

I'm using pure JSP in making my login page but every time I attempt to login it won't redirect to the page that I specified. Can someone tell me what's seems to be wrong with my code.
**Login**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="loginUser.jsp" method="post">
     <div class="form-group">
         <label class="control-label col-lg-5 col-md-6">Username:   </label>
              <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-6">   
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username">
              </div>
     </div>
    <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-lg-5 col-md-6">Password:   </label>
                <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-6">   
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="password">
                 </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group"> 
          <div class="col-lg-offset-9 col-lg-9 col-md-6">  
                <button type="submit" name="login" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
           </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

**loginUser.jsp**

```
<%
            String user = request.getParameter("username");
            String pass = request.getParameter("password");


            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }


            Connection conn = null;
            Statement stmt = null;

            try {
                conn =
                    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/webapp_java?" +
                                           "user=root&password=");

                stmt = conn.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs;
                rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='"+user+"', password='"+pass+"' ");

                if(rs.next()) { 
                   if(rs.getString("role").equals("Admin")){
                       session.setAttribute("userSession", user);
                       response.sendRedirect("display.jsp");
                   }
                   else{
                       response.sendRedirect("viewItems.jsp");
                   }

                }
                else{
                  out.println("Invalid fields <a href='login.jsp'>Try again!</a>");
                }

            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                System.err.println(ex.getMessage());

            }


    %>
```

Comment: you get blank page is that your problem

Comment: where you got redirected viewItems.jsp or display.jsp ?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='"+user+"' AND  password='"+pass+"' `

Comment: stop doing this and print the stacktrace catch (Exception ex) {
            }

Comment: @DarkKnight yes, sir I get blank page

Comment: @manikantgautam no, sir. I got a blank page instead

Comment: @SearchAndResQ is there something wrong with the statement, sir?

Comment: @KaelJasper print stack trace in first catch in loginUser.jsp and check

Comment: You should use prepared statements to prevent SQL Injections.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added an AND to the where clause of my SQL statement.